# Make the buil-in classbased view know the application namespace in Django

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

So,I am trying to implement password change functionality using built-in class based views(PasswordChangeView and PasswordChangeDoneView).
Now, when I enter the old password, new password and confirm password fields in the built-in template and hit enter(or submit) I get a "no reverse match" error saying "Reverse for 'password_change_done' not found. 'password_change_done' is not a valid view function or pattern name." I have researched a lot and found out that its because I am using the application namespace(app_name='authenticationApp' in urls.py) thats why django is not able to find the reverse. My simple question is How do I let the built-in view know that its supposed to use namespaced URL in the reverse function ?

PS: I know using my own template would resolve the issue. 
Edit 1:

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/password_change/

Django Version: 2.1.1
Python Version: 3.6.7
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'authenticationApp.apps.AuthenticationappConfig']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']


Traceback:

File "/home/python/Desktop/environments/second/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "/home/python/Desktop/environments/second/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/home/python/Desktop/environments/second/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  124.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/home/python/Desktop/environments/second/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  68.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/python/Desktop/environments/second/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  45.         return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)

File "/home/python/Desktop/environments/second/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/debug.py" in sensitive_post_parameters_wrapper
  76.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/python/Desktop/environments/second/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  45.         return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)

File "/home/python/Desktop/environments/second/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  142.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/python/Desktop/environments/second/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  45.         return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)

File "/home/python/Desktop/environments/second/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  21.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/python/Desktop/environments/second/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/views.py" in dispatch
  338.         return super().dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

File "/home/python/Desktop/environments/second/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
  88.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/python/Desktop/environments/second/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py" in post
  142.             return self.form_valid(form)

File "/home/python/Desktop/environments/second/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/views.py" in form_valid
  350.         return super().form_valid(form)

File "/home/python/Desktop/environments/second/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py" in form_valid
  57.         return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())

File "/home/python/Desktop/environments/second/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py" in get_success_url
  51.         if not self.success_url:

File "/home/python/Desktop/environments/second/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py" in __wrapper__
  108.                 res = func(*self.__args, **self.__kw)

File "/home/python/Desktop/environments/second/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/base.py" in reverse
  90.     return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))

File "/home/python/Desktop/environments/second/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py" in _reverse_with_prefix
  622.         raise NoReverseMatch(msg)

Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /password_change/
Exception Value: Reverse for 'password_change_done' not found. 'password_change_done' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your main `urls.py`(which resides beside `settings.py`), you should import your views like this:

```
path('password_change/', views.PasswordChangeView.as_view(template_name='your_template.html'), name='password_change'),  # or your path
path('password_change/done/', views.PasswordChangeDoneView.as_view(), name='password_change_done'),
```

Comment: I just did that. Now I get a new error after I hit submit of the login form that admin is not a registered namespace

Comment: Are you using the default login view by `django.contrib.auth`? If you are planning to use django's default auth implementation, consider using it like this: `path('your_url/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls'))`. Also please read this documentation as well: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/default/#module-django.contrib.auth.views

Comment: Yes I am using the default login view. But instead of using them as mentioned above I am directly importing the django.contrib.auth.views in my urls.py

Comment: please add `path('admin/', admin.site.urls)` in your root urls.py and see if the error persists. If the error persists, then please update your question with full error stacktrace

Comment: So, The admin error is removed but the the original error still remains

Comment: can you add the full stacktrace to the question please?

Comment: Added the stacktrace

Comment: did you not add `path('password_change/done/', views.PasswordChangeDoneView.as_view(), name='password_change_done'),` at your root `urls.py`?

Comment: Wow. That has magically worked now but I have no idea whats going on. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: But I had added it in my app's urls.py Why wasnt it taking that ?

Comment: then the url name becomes `app_name:password_change_done`. Please check the docs regarding namespaces in here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces